# How can we let our web designers code complex web apps without a server side language?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my web development company, we have many designers who have the following dev knowledge and experience:

- Client-side web languages (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)
- Basic database design (how to create tables, relationships, etc), and
- Basic SQL

The problem is that those guys *don't* know a server side language, such as C#. We want to give them an option to create web apps with their current knowledge.

Basically, they should be able to create data grids, add/edit forms, etc, without the use of a full server side language such as C# or PHP.

We don't want to create new huge new technologies here. We want a simple solution, that is easy to understand and maintain and possibly somewhat open source.

We thought about adding an extension to ASP.NET Razor, that looks something like this:

```
@DB(table="pages", where="id > 15")

<ul>
@while (row.Next()) {
    <li><a href="@row.URL">@row.Name</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

Is this a good solution, in terms of performance, design patterns, code style and security (SQL Injections)?

Is there anything open source for this?

Do you have any other ideas?

---

Here are some examples for a simple app that uses this style:

**/apps/pages/index.html**

```
@(DB.Select(table: "pages", 
            where: "id = ? and date > ?",
            params: new[] { Request.QueryString["ID"], Request.QueryString["Date"] }))

<html>
<body>
    <ul>
    @foreach (var row in Model) {
        <li><a href="@row.URL">@row.Name</a></li>
    }
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**/apps/pages/create.html**

```
@(DB.InsertOnPost(table: "pages",
                  fields: "name, description, date",
                  values: "?, ?, Now",
                  params: new[] { Request.Form["Name"], Request.Form["Description"] }))

@RedirectOnPost("/pages")

<form action="/pages/create" method=”post”>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

**/apps/pages/edit.html**

```
@(DB.UpdateOnPost(table: "pages",
                  set: "name = ?, description = ?",
                  where: "id = ?",
                  params: new[] { Request.Form["Name"], Request.Form["Description"], 
                                  Request.QueryString["ID"] }))

@RedirectOnPost("/pages")

@(DB.Select(table: "pages", 
            where: "id = ?",
            params: new[] { Request.QueryString["ID"] })

<form action="/pages/edit" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="@Model.Name" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea name="description">@Model.Description</textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you could just expose a WebApiController and they can use jQuery/AJAX (just understanding the actual data fetching/processing is pushed off to the client now).

Comment: Jquery with AJAX and a server-side developer to write Webservices for them to consume. Maybe Kendo for the front end Jquery?

Comment: If they are capable of writing complex client side code, they are capable of writing complex server side code. Programming is programming. Course you and they would be better off if they wrote simple code...

Comment: They are not capable of writing complex client side code. They are able to write some animation stuff using jQuery and that's it. Remember that they are web designers.

Comment: I think node.js is the best solution here because you can't directly connect to database from your client in a secure way. So if you don't want to learn a new server side language you can use node.

Comment: @BradChristie There's the SEO issue, we don't want "ajax-only apps"

Comment: @AlonGubkin: I have to say, UI guys are UI guys for a reason. May i ask why you want to push some of this off on to them? This is where communication and understanding requirements comes in; you should know what needs to be displayed, setup the means (view models) and let them pretty it up. If you have this much concern over how they can and will access the data, shouldn't that be a red flag to start? it seems to me you'd rather invest weeks in making it (safely) accessible instead of just plumbing it through for them.

Comment: @BradChristie Because we have so many web apps that are exactly the same for the web developer - add data, view data, edit data. For this type of simple apps, we want to give the UI guys the option to do it themselves.

Answer (score 6):

*IMHO*

I have to say, UI guys are UI guys for a reason. This is where communication and understanding requirements comes in. Both parties should have a clear grasp on what needs to be done to get the end product complete. It should never be a concern to the guys on the front end how to get the information, just like you should never have to worry about which style sheet is being used when you're writing a service or making a view model.

If it's a matter of too much work load on the back end, it may be time to look at just cleaning things up or making things more concise, but not handing off DB access to someone who doesn't know what they're doing.

If you have this much concern over how they can and will access the data, shouldn't that be a red flag to start? It seems to me you'd rather invest weeks (and it will be weeks since you'll have to sandbox everything) in making it safely accessible instead of just plumbing it through for them.

Do requirements ever get you there 100%? No. You will have some back and forth (either UI needs something, or you do) but that's the name of the game. The good part is most of the time you can work in tandem (they are working on how it will look while you give them the pieces they need to wire it up).

Answer (score 2):

I think you have several options here.

1. Get them to use node.js so they can use their JavaScript skills.
2. Get them to use Ruby on Rails, they will probably appreciate using a new technology, and you get a great framework to boot.

But probably more importantly, you should ask them what they think. You might be surprised.

Comment: Their JavaScript skills are not very high. Remember that they are web designers - they know just a little bit jQuery for some animation stuff.

Comment: About the RoR option - teaching them an entire new language and framework is not an option for us.

Comment: @AlonGubkin ok, then what you want? using js with node.js is not good and learning a new language neither. Then what you had in mind?

Comment: I thought about adding an extension to the view engine, look at my question

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data above, the fundamental conflicting datum is that you want them to be able to program something using a technology that they do not understand.  In my experience, this is not a good idea.  If no one on your team understands the ins and outs of server side development, you will end up with a low-quality product.

That said - the situation you are describing is quite common and this is thus a good question. My suggestion is that you should reorganize your team and workflow rather than trying to see how you can solve this by using a "simpler" technology (I put it in quotes because often attempts to make something simpler work for one set of problems, but as the requirements change those simplifications just start getting your way and it's then no longer simpler.)

Some specific options:

- Hire one additional person with "backend coding" skillz and have them deal with all of the back end work.  (Note that it's not all that important which backend language we're talking about - C#, PHP, Java, Python, etc. - the same principle applies - it's a different/more involved set of technical skills required as compared to doing UI scripting.  And on the other hand, this person doesn't require any of the graphic design sense which a UI developer should have.)
- Or, designate one of your existing team to bone up on these skills and while it will take them for them to learn - you at least have one specific person who will eventually be the guy who knows all about it.

Whoever this person is, should be in charge of selecting which framework to use.  And they should do it with as much of an understanding of the particular problems specific to your project, etc.

Additionally, there are some technical approaches that could provide better separation.  One idea is you could write API calls that provide JSON data which the UI people can then access using JQuery or similar tools.  This way your backend code is all in one file and just returns data - making it more clear who is doing what.  Example:

/api/some-data.php: (the "backend guy" edits this)

```
// do some work to get some data
$myData = ...;
// dump it out as JSON
print json_encode($myData);
```

/some-page-that-uses-data.html: (the "UI guy" edits this)

```
<!-- simple jQuery AJAX call -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ url:'/api/some-data.php' }).done(data) {
        // do something to populate the page with the data...
    };
});
</script>
```

(NOTE: You can use JSONP or CORS to get around cross domain problems if you run into that.)

---

**Overall - instead of trying to have UI guys do work in an area they are not familiar with, separate the work so that people can specialize and each one does a good job on his/her part.  You don't need a bunch of people to be server-side ninjas - but you need at least one...**